# Use swagger codegen cli to generate Node.js server with models

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, swagger

I have a **swagger.yaml** and just installed the **swagger-codegen** on my Mac. I want to generate a Node.js server including the models described in the swagger.yaml from the command line. I tried:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.yaml -l nodejs -o export/nodejs -Dmodels
```

and

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.yaml -l nodejs -o export/nodejs -Dmodels -DsupportingFiles
```

But the output is always the same **WITHOUT** the models:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opposed to previous versions of swagger-node (fka swagger-node-express), the swagger definition is used as the source of truth.  There is no model file generated for each model in the application.  So the -Dmodels will have no effect.

You can generate the response payload and send it back, and even configure the framework to validate that it follows the definition.

Comment: Do you have an example for that? Not sure how to handle persistence with swagger and mongoose.