# Swagger js codegen on how to generate models

Tags: node.js, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger js codegen to generate source code in nodejs .it works superb.

However i have question ,

If we use swagger codegen and use java lang , models and handlers gets generated as part of stubs generation but in swagger js codegen it does not generate any models.

can you please guide me if we can generate models in swagger js codegen .This will actually help when there is an change in api it will automatically generate the models without we manually changing.

Kindly suggest if any other approach is available for nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559725/use-swagger-codegen-cli-to-generate-node-js-server-with-models) what you need?

quoting, "As opposed to previous versions of swagger-node (fka swagger-node-express), the swagger definition is used as the source of truth. There is no model file generated for each model in the application. So the -Dmodels will have no effect.

You can generate the response payload and send it back, and even configure the framework to validate that it follows the definition."